# PHP substr breaks emoji

Tags: php, emoji

I need to get only 30 characters from the paragraph submitted by user. In case the 30th character is an emoji, the output shows question marks. How can I avoid breaking the emojis?

echo substr("Hello world Hello world Hell ", 0, 30);

Output: Hello world Hello world Hell��

Also, when using json_encode to return the output, the output is blank.

```
$myvariable = array();
$myvariable['hello'] = substr("Hello world Hello world Hell ", 0, 30);
echo json_encode($myvariable);
```

Comment: Maybe [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

Comment: echo json_encode($output,JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR); Fixes json_encode giving blank output. 
Incase, anyone lands on this page from google search, this might be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be to use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

> Performs a multi-byte safe substr() operation based on number of
>   characters.

```
php > $myvariable = array();
php > $myvariable['hello'] = mb_substr("Hello world Hello world Hell ", 0, 30);
php > var_dump($myvariable);
array(1) {
  ["hello"]=>
  string(33) "Hello world Hello world Hell "
}
php > echo json_encode($myvariable);
{"hello":"Hello world Hello world Hell\ud83d\ude04 "}
php >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> 

OR

function entities( $string ) {
    $stringBuilder = "";
    $offset = 0;

    if ( empty( $string ) ) {
        return "";
    }

    while ( $offset >= 0 ) {
        $decValue = ordutf8( $string, $offset );
        $char = unichr($decValue);

        $htmlEntited = htmlentities( $char );
        if( $char != $htmlEntited ){
            $stringBuilder .= $htmlEntited;
        } elseif( $decValue >= 128 ){
            $stringBuilder .= "&#" . $decValue . ";";
        } else {
            $stringBuilder .= $char;
        }
    }

    return $stringBuilder;
}

// source - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php#109812
function ordutf8($string, &$offset) {
    $code = ord(substr($string, $offset,1));
    if ($code >= 128) {        //otherwise 0xxxxxxx
        if ($code < 224) $bytesnumber = 2;                //110xxxxx
        else if ($code < 240) $bytesnumber = 3;        //1110xxxx
        else if ($code < 248) $bytesnumber = 4;    //11110xxx
        $codetemp = $code - 192 - ($bytesnumber > 2 ? 32 : 0) - ($bytesnumber > 3 ? 16 : 0);
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $bytesnumber; $i++) {
            $offset ++;
            $code2 = ord(substr($string, $offset, 1)) - 128;        //10xxxxxx
            $codetemp = $codetemp*64 + $code2;
        }
        $code = $codetemp;
    }
    $offset += 1;
    if ($offset >= strlen($string)) $offset = -1;
    return $code;
}

// source - http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php#88611
function unichr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}

/* ---- */

var_dump( entities( "&" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "<" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "☚" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "A" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "Hello  world" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "this & that " ) ) . "\n";
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of what the code does and how it solves what issue, not just a blob of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($m) {
    $char = current($m);
    $utf = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4', $char);
    return sprintf("&#x%s;", ltrim(strtoupper(bin2hex($utf)), "0"));
}, $string);
```

Output

```
string 'Fran&#xE7;ais' (length=13)
```

**OR**

```
echo json_decode('"\uD83D\uDE00"');
```

Comment: Why are you writing multiple answers? Pick the best one and remove any other. One of them should be preferred over the other, no? And you still should include an explanation.